# sess_regenerate doesn't work in CodeIgniter 3.01

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, authentication, logout

I have login form here: http://localhost/AuctionsApp/account/login

In controller I have this code:

```
// Logowanie
    public function login()
    {

        // Sprawdzenie czy user jest zalogowany, jeśli tak to nastepuje przekierowanie do strony głównej
        logged_in() == false || redirect ( '/' );

        if ( !empty( $_POST ) )
        {

            if ( $this->form_validation->run( 'site_account_login' ) == true )
            {

                $username = $this->input->post( 'username' , true );
                $password = $this->input->post( 'password' , true );

                $where = array( 'username' => $username );
                $user = $this->Site->get_single( 'users' , $where );

                if ( !empty( $user ) ) 
                {

                    if( password_verify( $password , $user->password ) == 1 ) 
                    {

                        // Sprawdzenie czy użytkownik jest aktywny
                        if( $user->is_active == 1 )
                        {
                            // Zalogowanie użytkownika
                            $data_login = array(
                                'id' => $user->id,
                                'username' => $user->username,
                                'email' => $user->email,
                                'logged_in' => true
                            );

                            $this->session->set_userdata( $data_login );

                            // Zapamiętaj mnie
                            if ( $this->input->post( 'remember' , true ) == 1 ) 
                            {

                                $remember_code = random_string();

                                $where = array( 'id' => $user->id );
                                $data = array( 'remember_code' => $remember_code );
                                $this->Site->update( 'users' , $where , $data );

                                $user_info_array = array(
                                    'id' => $user->id,
                                    'username' => $user->username,
                                    'email' => $user->email,
                                    'logged_in' => true,
                                    'remember_code' => $remember_code
                                );

                                $user_info_json = json_encode( $user_info_array );

                                $data_cookie = array(
                                    'name' => 'remember_me',
                                    'value' => $user_info_json,
                                    'expire' => 60*60*24*365,
                                    'path' => '/',
                                );

                                set_cookie( $data_cookie );

                            }

                            // Przekierowanie do strony głównej i wyświetlenie komunikatu
                            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Zalogowałeś się poprawnie!' );
                            redirect( '/' );

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Musisz aktywować konto, żeby się zalogować!' );
                            refresh();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Użytkownik podał złe hasło
                        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Błędne hasło.' );
                        refresh();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    // Uzytkownik nie istnieje
                    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Użytkownik nie istnieje.' );
                    refresh();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , validation_errors() );
                refresh();
            }

        }

        // Ładowanie widoku
        $this->load->view( 'site/account/login' );

    }
```

I want to create a logout so I created a new functions:

```
// Wylogowywanie
    public function logout() 
    {

        $this->session->sess_regenerate( true );
        delete_cookie( 'remember_me' );

        // Wyswietlenie komunikatu i przekierowanie do strony głównej
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Wylogowałeś się.' );
        redirect( '/' );

    }
```

When I enter in: http://localhost/AuctionsApp/account/logout, I get the message and redirected but I can not go back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to handle this using two classes

- First create two new classes called ***Login*** and ***Logout***,
- Then inside ***login*** create a function called ***validate***,
- Then inside ***logout*** class use the ***index*** function just to **destroy** the
  **session** and redirect user to the login

**Login** class,

```
public function validate()

{
    // Sprawdzenie czy user jest zalogowany, jeśli tak to nastepuje przekierowanie do strony głównej
    logged_in() == false || redirect('/');
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        if ($this->form_validation->run('site_account_login') == true) {
            $username = $this->input->post('username', true);
            $password = $this->input->post('password', true);
            $where = array(
                'username' => $username
            );
            $user = $this->Site->get_single('users', $where);
            if (!empty($user)) {
                if (password_verify($password, $user->password) == 1) {
                    // Sprawdzenie czy użytkownik jest aktywny
                    if ($user->is_active == 1) {
                        // Zalogowanie użytkownika
                        $data_login = array(
                            'id' => $user->id,
                            'username' => $user->username,
                            'email' => $user->email,
                            'logged_in' => true
                        );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($data_login);
                        // Zapamiętaj mnie
                        if ($this->input->post('remember', true) == 1) {
                            $remember_code = random_string();
                            $where = array(
                                'id' => $user->id
                            );
                            $data = array(
                                'remember_code' => $remember_code
                            );
                            $this->Site->update('users', $where, $data);
                            $user_info_array = array(
                                'id' => $user->id,
                                'username' => $user->username,
                                'email' => $user->email,
                                'logged_in' => true,
                                'remember_code' => $remember_code
                            );
                            $user_info_json = json_encode($user_info_array);
                            $data_cookie = array(
                                'name' => 'remember_me',
                                'value' => $user_info_json,
                                'expire' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
                                'path' => '/',
                            );
                            set_cookie($data_cookie);
                        }
                        // Przekierowanie do strony głównej i wyświetlenie komunikatu
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Zalogowałeś się poprawnie!');
                        redirect('/');
                    }
                    else {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Musisz aktywować konto, żeby się zalogować!');
                        refresh();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // Użytkownik podał złe hasło
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Błędne hasło.');
                    refresh();
                }
            }
            else {
                // Uzytkownik nie istnieje
                $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Użytkownik nie istnieje.');
                refresh();
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('alert', validation_errors());
            refresh();
        }
    }
    // Ładowanie widoku
    $this->load->view('site/account/login');
}
```

**Logout** class

```
public function index()

{
    $user_datas = $this->session->all_userdata();
    foreach($user_datas as $key => $user_data) {
        $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
    }
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Wylogowałeś się.' );
    redirect('login');
}
```

Comment: I can also add sess_destroy to my function, but then the message is not displayed.

Comment: @zf2newbie what message you want to display?..`sess_regenerate` will regenerate the session id.

Comment: @zf2newbie i have updated my code...you can add any message you want.